# Ubuntu 20.04 KVM kernel for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, kernel, ubuntu, qemu, virtualization

I would like to deploy a VM from KVM template on Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu server 20.04. 
The VM will be configured with an emulated x86_64 CPU. 
Is there a precompiled KVM kernel for it? 
If not, how do I compile a KVM kernel for it?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: I will narrow the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Ubuntu 20.04 ARM64 already supports KVM acceleration on Raspberry Pi 4.
This is how I checked:
[https://linuxhint.com/install_kvm_ubuntu/#:~:text=You%20can%20check%20whether%20KVM,is%20not%20installed%20by%20default](https://linuxhint.com/install_kvm_ubuntu/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20check%20whether%20KVM,is%20not%20installed%20by%20default).

Answer (score 0):

This gist contains what you need to build a RPi 4 kernel with KVM for Ubuntu.

https://gist.github.com/rhtyd/dbb23adf5239ac098f9a1e7b2824121d

Comment: This is for Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Same logic for 20.04, just change the preinstalled-server image to 20.04 instead of 19.10.